# After extending the User model in django, how do you create a ModelForm?

Tags: django, extend, modelform

I extended the User model in django to include several other variables, such as location, and employer. Now I'm trying to create a form that has the following fields:

```
First name (from User)
Last name (from User)
Location (from UserProfile, which extends User via a foreign key)
Employer (also from UserProfile)
```

I have created a modelform:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib import auth
from alert.userHandling.models import UserProfile

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
#       model = auth.models.User # this gives me the User fields
        model = UserProfile # this gives me the UserProfile fields
```

So, my question is, how can I create a ModelForm that has access to all of the fields, whether they are from the User model or the UserProfile model?

Hope this makes sense. I'll be happy to clarify if there are any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create two model forms (one for User and one for UserProfile) or create a custom form with all your fields and dispatch them in your view.

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    location = forms.CharField()
    employer = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: I just did this, and it's working. Establishing two modelforms and viewing them both in the template works like a charm.

Comment: Oh, and lest I forget, thanks so much for the help! This site is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `ModelForm` expects all its fields to come from a single model. Create a child of `Form` and pull the field definitions from the models.