# Extending django UserCreationForm

Tags: django, forms, customization

Well, I extended User:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sheba = models.DecimalField(max_digits= SHEBA_LENGTH, decimal_places = 0)
    mellicode = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places = 0)
```

But the problem is that we have `UserCreationForm` for user signup. Now I need a new form to handle added fields. I like to create the form from model using `ModelForm`. Now the problem is that `UserCreationForm` itself uses `ModelForm` to create fields for `User` model. `ModelForm` has an inner class named `Meta` which have a field named model for specifying what model should be read for wanted field. I thought there should be a way to do so as it is an ordinary thing to do.

What I have now which doesn't work for obvious reasons is this:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm, ModelForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user','mellicode', 
        'birthdate','residentialaddress','postalcode','sheba','idpic']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511759/after-extending-the-user-model-in-django-how-do-you-create-a-modelform?rq=1 is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article from this clever [guy](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone), you can make your new UserProfile Model to automatically create/update whenever a new User instance created or existing instance updated using the following extension to your model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sheba = models.DecimalField(max_digits= SHEBA_LENGTH, decimal_places = 0)
    mellicode = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places = 0)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.user_profile.save()
```

Because Django allows you to process two forms at once in your view, you can solve your problem using the following approach:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('sheba', 'mellicode')
```

And then in your views.py:

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def create_user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
         user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
         if user_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
             user_form.save()
             user_profile_form.save()
             messages.success(request, "User successfully created")
         else:
             messages.error(request, "Correct errors")
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.user_profile)
    return render(request, 'create_profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'user_profile_form': user_profile_form
    })
```

And in your template you will render two forms as this:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ user_form.as_p }}
  {{ profile_form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had already read that article but that solution seems like a hack or workaround to me. I thought about it and I think the problem is that ModelForm is not designed to be used in a form that is inheriting from another form which inherits from ModelForm.